# Quantstrat WFA with intraday Data

Tags: r, quantstrat

I've been getting WFA to run on the full set of intraday GBPUSD 30min data, and have come across a couple of things that need addressing. The first is I believe the save function needs changing to remove the time from the string (as shown [here](https://github.com/R-Finance/quantstrat/pull/2/commits/9923b77febdca2de68cea653b261cfe02bb5a198) as a pull request on the R-Finance/quantstrat repo on github). The `walk.forward` function throws this error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'wfa.GBPUSD.2002-10-21 00:30:00.2002-10-23 23:30:00.RData', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
```

The second is a rare case scenario where its ends up calling `runSum` on a data set with less rows than the period you are testing (`n`). This is the `traceback()`:

```
8: stop("Invalid 'n'")
7: runSum(x, n)
6: runMean(x, n)
5: (function (x, n = 10, ...) 
   {
       ma <- runMean(x, n)
       if (!is.null(dim(ma))) {
       colnames(ma) <- "SMA"
   }
   return(ma)
   })(x = Cl(mktdata)[, 1], n = 25)
4: do.call(indFun, .formals)
3: applyIndicators(strategy = strategy, mktdata = mktdata, parameters = parameters, 
   ...)
2: applyStrategy(strategy, portfolios = portfolio.st, mktdata = symbol[testing.timespan]) at custom.walk.forward.R#122
1: walk.forward(strategy.st, paramset.label = "WFA", portfolio.st = portfolio.st, 
   account.st = account.st, period = "days", k.training = 3, 
   k.testing = 1, obj.func = my.obj.func, obj.args = list(x = quote(result$apply.paramset)), 
   audit.prefix = "wfa", anchored = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

The extended GBPUSD data used in the creation of the Luxor Demo includes an erroneous date (2002/10/27) with only 1 observation which causes this problem. I can also foresee this being an issue when testing longer signal periods on instruments like Crude where they have only a few trading hours on Sunday evenings (UTC).

Given that I have purely been following the Luxor demo with the same (extended) intra-day data set, are these genuine issues or have they been caused by package updates etc?

What is the preferred way for these things to be reported to the authors of QS, and find out if/when fixes are likely to be made?

`SessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantstrat_0.9.1739           foreach_1.4.3                 blotter_0.9.1741              PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.4000 FinancialInstrument_1.2.0     quantmod_0.4-5                TTR_0.23-1                   
[8] xts_0.9.874                   zoo_1.7-13                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.3.0   tools_3.3.0      codetools_0.2-14 grid_3.3.0       iterators_1.0.8  lattice_0.20-33
```

Answer (score 0):

`quantstrat` is on github here:
https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat

Issues and patches should be reported via github issues.